# How to join two table in symfony 5?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I'm a beginner in Symfony and here is my problem.

More precisely, I have two table in my DB. The first one is called 'post' and the other is called 'article'. The post table is the parent entity of article which mean that the article entity inherite from the post entity. What I would like to is to join this two table to get data from my database.

However, after reading the doctrine and symfony docs about mapping inheritance, I still cannot solve my problem.

Could you help me to solve this problem please ?

N.B : here is my code

Article class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Articles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticlesRepository")
 */
class Articles
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="post", type="integer", nullable=false )
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $themes;

    /**
     * Articles constructor.
     * @param int $post
     */

    public static $themeAvailable = [
        0 => "Environnement",
        1 => "Economie",
        2 => "Science et technologie",
        3 => "Loisir",
        4 => "Culture générale",
        5 => "Art",
        6 => "Sport"
    ];

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPost(): ?int
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    public function getThemes(): ?string
    {
        return $this->themes;
    }

    public function setThemes(string $themes): self
    {
        $this->themes = $themes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setPost(int $post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }


}
```

Post class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Posts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostsRepository")
 */
class Posts
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "20M",
     *     maxSizeMessage = "La taille du fichier trop importante. Minimum autorisé : 20 Mo.",
     *     mimeTypes = {"image/svg","image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif" },
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Format du fichier incorrecte. Formats autorisés : svg, png, jpg, jpeg, gif.",
     *     disallowEmptyMessage = "Veuillez importer une image supérieur à 0 Mo."
     *     )
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="blob", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /**
     * Posts constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->creationDate = new \DateTime();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?int
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage($image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreationDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    public function setCreationDate(\DateTimeInterface $creationDate): self
    {
        $this->creationDate = $creationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setAuthor(int $author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;
    }


}
```

My Repository :

```
public function findAllArticle()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->join('a.post',
            'p')
        ->addSelect('p')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

And here is my controller :

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\Articles;
use App\Entity\Posts;
use App\Form\PostsArticleType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class PostArticleController extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * ArticleController constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/post/create", name="index")
     * @return Response
     */

    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/post/article/show", name="showArticle")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(): Response
    {
        $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository(Articles::class)
            ->findAllArticle();
        return $this->render('post/showArticle.html.twig', array('article' => $articles));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/post/article/new", name="newArticle")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $post = new Posts();
        $article = new Articles();
        $post->setAuthor(1);
        $form = $this->createForm(PostsArticleType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $this->em->persist($post);
            $this->em->flush();
            $article->setPost($post->getId());
            $themes = $form->get('themes')->getData();
            $article->setThemes(implode(',', $themes));
            $this->em->persist($article);
            $this->em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home.html.twig');
        }

        return $this->render('post/CreateArticle.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have two tables posts and articles, you can use "JOINED" inheritance:
The Posts class should look like:

```
/*...*/
/**
 * Posts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostsRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"posts" = "Posts", "articles" = "Articles"})
 */
class Posts
{
    /*...*/
}
```

For Articles class:

```
/*...*/
/**
 * Articles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticlesRepository")
 */
class Articles extends Posts
{
    /*...*/
}
```

- For the posts table, you will have the Posts class properties, and a column called 'discr' configured in DiscriminatorColumn parameter (see Posts class).
- For the articles table, you will have the Articles class properties, and 'posts_id' column, which is a foreign key (it references 'id' column of 'posts' table).

There are some helpful links :

[Doctrine : Class Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)

[About Doctrine inheritance](https://romaricdrigon.github.io/2019/06/11/doctrine-inheritance) - Section: Class Table Inheritance

Comment: ty for your solution, but I'm wondering what I have to write in my ArticleRepository to fetch the post which are only of type article and nothing else ?

Comment: Try :
public function findAllArticle()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->getQuery()->getResult();
}

In ArticlesRepository class.

Comment: Ty for your answer